# How much does a metal filter affect extraction time?

Tags: extraction, filter

I'm investigating reusable metal filters for drip coffee makers or pour-over, and the information online seems counter-intuitive.

Online discussion about the difference always describes how the metal filters have bigger pores than paper filters, so you get more sediment and oils in the coffee with metal filters. But the discussions leave out the obvious question of how the pore size difference affects extraction.

There is a big range of pore sizes in metal filters (20-800 microns vs. 10-20 microns for paper), so there must be a lot of variation in their effect. But if sediment is getting through a metal filter, the larger pores would allow water to flow through more quickly.

This means that for drip coffee makers or pour-over, the grinds are in contact with the water for a shorter time, which would result in less extraction.

Less extraction should result in a "brighter" (more acidic) flavor profile, and fruity and sweet flavors less masked, maybe even weaker flavor. However, the discussions conflate the "body" contributed by the fines and oils (and maybe the flavors of those), and claim that it's paper filters, instead, which yield a flavor profile associated with lower extraction.

**My question:** Compared to paper filters, do metal filters have an appreciable effect on extraction time (and extraction level), when used with drip coffee makers or pour-over?

Comment: Generally filters are applied to brews AFTER brewing. What brewing method do you have in mind that has you thinking filter type would make any difference at all to extraction?